# Need assistance on creating for loop

Tags: python-3.x, file, for-loop

I'm trying to write bytes from one file to a second file, then go back to the first file and delete the bytes written. I'm doing this one byte at a time (first byte essentially copied and written to 2nd file, then that byte is removed from the first file).

The problem I'm having is creating a for loop (assuming that's the best way to go about this) to make this happen. My current code is below:

```
in_file = open('file', "rb")
data = in_file.read()
length = len(in_file.read())
in_file.close()

out_file = open('file2', "wb")
out_file.write(data[length:length+1])
out_file.close()

in_file = open('file', "wb")
in_file.write(data[1:])
in_file.close()

in_file = open('file', "rb")
data = in_file.read()
length = len(in_file.read())
in_file.close()

out_file = open('file2', "ab")
out_file.write(data[length:length+1])
out_file.close()

in_file = open('file', "wb")
in_file.write(data[1:])
in_file.close()

in_file = open('file', "rb")
data = in_file.read()
length = len(in_file.read())
in_file.close()

out_file = open('file2', "ab")
out_file.write(data[length:length+1])
out_file.close()

in_file = open('file', "wb")
in_file.write(data[1:])
in_file.close()
```

I guess the way I saw this happening is I get the first byte written outside of the loop, and then I have a for loop for appending each subsequent byte between the two files. I've tried creating a for loop for that sequence but I keep receiving errors about trying to access the closed file, so I'm not sure when/where to "close" my file. Reason I'm doing this is eventually I will convert each byte (files I'm dealing with are obfuscated bytes and I need to convert them back) to a difference byte value.

I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Keep the 2 files open until you're done. Don't keep closing and reopening.

Comment: If I don't close them out it doesn't write the new data/change data between the files like I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the 2 files open until you're done. Closing and opening files can't happen as fast your program tries to execute them.

You may have to [flush](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_flush.htm) the file object before you do the final (and only) close, *i.e.*

```
in_file.close(); // no need to flush the in-file
out_file.flush(); // do flush the out-file
out_file.close();
```